# Google Sheets change background color based on value of another cell

Tags: google-sheets, time, calculation

In Google Sheets, is there a way to change not just the value but also the background color of a cell based on one of several possible values of another cell??

In other words,

If A1 is > 2, then B1 should be background color blue

I would like to change the background color of the cell E that are not 0:00. Here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NSBx87sWScwe2Vtp9FOcH3BupvPJ_jzISUeAk6gSBOM/edit?usp=sharing

What's the syntax to write this kind of matching?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at Format menu -> Conditional Formatting, where you can use formula to decide what formatting can be applied.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google Sheets has a native solution for this.

Just right click on the cell(s) you want to change background color and choose `Conditional formatting`, it is the penultimate option.

Then a right side tab with the different formatting rules will open. There you can define the range, the rules and the formatting style.

Source: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en

Comment: Oh interesting. Thanks for this. This doesn't seem to work if there's already a function in the cell or do I miss something? Tried this in the file here on E5:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NSBx87sWScwe2Vtp9FOcH3BupvPJ_jzISUeAk6gSBOM/edit#gid=612415402

Comment: The rule will be applied according to the result displayed in the cell. Cell functions do not influence conditional formatting rules.